# The number of option to fill a given shape

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Given a two 1d arrays that are stick one to the other with n and m lengths , write a recursive algorithm to find the number of ways that this shape  could be filled by 1x1 or 1x2 or 2x1 blocks ,
[image: The arrays that we need to fill]

here is my attempt , but I believe that I'm counting the same option several times :

```
public static int foo(int n1 ,int m){
if(n1==0 &&  m ==0){
    return 1;
}
if(n1 < 0 || m < 0)
    return 0;

  return (foo(n1-1,m)+foo(n1,m-1)+foo(n1-1,m-1) +foo(n1,m-2) + foo(n1-2,m));


}
```

*** UPDATE ****
now the code compiles.

Examples : 
input foo(2,2) output : 21 , the right answer is 7 .
input foo(4,3) output : 417, the right answer is 32.

these are the options for foo(2,2).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll assume `n < m`. If this is not the case we can just reverse the arguments - this makes the code simpler.

Once we've dealt with the terminating conditions we use a decrease-and-conquer strategy to reduce the input according to the following rules: if `n == m`, we can reduce both `n & m` by 1 two ways, `n & m` by 2 one way, `n` by 1 and `m` by 2 one way, and `n` by 2 and `m` by 1 one way. If `n < m` we can reduce `m` by 1 one way and `m` by 2 one way.

```
static int foo(int n, int m)
{           
    if(n > m) return foo(m, n);

    if(n < 0 || m < 0) return 0;

    if(n == 0 && m == 0) return 1;

    if(n == m) return 2*foo(n-1, m-1) + foo(n-2, m-2) + foo(n-1, m-2) + foo(n-2, m-1);

    return foo(n, m-1) + foo(n, m-2);
}
```

Test:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    for(int j=i; j<5; j++)
        System.out.format("(%d, %d) = %d%n", i, j, foo(i, j));
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) = 1
(0, 1) = 1
(0, 2) = 2
(0, 3) = 3
(0, 4) = 5
(1, 1) = 2
(1, 2) = 3
(1, 3) = 5
(1, 4) = 8
(2, 2) = 7
(2, 3) = 10
(2, 4) = 17
(3, 3) = 22
(3, 4) = 32
(4, 4) = 71
```

For the case `n == m` (2, 7, 22, 71, ...) this is a known integer sequence ([A030186](https://oeis.org/A030186)).

And just for reference, here are the 32 configurations for (3,4):

[image]

Comment: No, you're lecturer was right - lecturers are always right :) I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that i have found the correct answer to my question  :

**yet i'm not closing this problem until someone with better knowledge than me confirm my answer**

```
public static int foo(int n1 ,int m){
   if(n1==0 &&  m ==0){
  return 1;
 }
   if(n1 < 0 || m < 0)
      return 0;
  if(m == n1){
    return Integer.max(foo(n1-1,m),foo(n1,m-1)) + Integer.max(foo(n1-2,m),foo(n1,m-2))+ foo(n1-1,m-1);
  }else{
   return Integer.max(foo(n1-1,m),foo(n1,m-1)) + Integer.max(foo(n1-2,m),foo(n1,m-2));
   }

   }
```

now i'm taking only the maximum sub-Problem answer so I won't count the same option more than once.